# sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper expression 'XXXX' failed to locate a name

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm starting my journey on a Python FastAPI project, with SQLAlchemy and a PostgreSQL db.
I'm working on the "users domain" for now, and I succesfully mapped the first entities, using SQLAlchemy models and my first Alembic migration following their respective docs.

This is the screenshot of the ER diagram of my local db after the first migration (taken from DBeaver).

[image]

Here's my main db.py file:

```
## db.py

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, DeclarativeBase
from src.config import settings

engine = create_engine(settings.db_connection_string, echo=True)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass
```

Below my models for User, Role and the association table

```
## users\models.py

from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy import String, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, Mapped, mapped_column

from src.database.db import Base
from src.usersDomain.associations import UsersRolesTable

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    primary_email: Mapped[str | None] = mapped_column(String, unique=True)
    creation_date: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(DateTime)

    accounts: Mapped[list["Account"]] = relationship(back_populates="user")
    roles: Mapped[list["Role"]] = relationship(secondary=UsersRolesTable, back_populates="users")
```

```
## roles\models.py

from sqlalchemy import Boolean, Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, Mapped, mapped_column

from src.database.db import Base
from src.usersDomain.associations import RolesPermissionsTable, UsersRolesTable


class Role(Base):
    __tablename__ = "roles"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String, unique=True, index=True)
    description: Mapped[str | None] = mapped_column(String)

    users: Mapped[list["User"]] = relationship(secondary=UsersRolesTable, back_populates="roles")
    permissions: Mapped[list["Permission"]] = relationship(secondary=RolesPermissionsTable, back_populates="roles")
```

```
## associations.py

from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Table
from src.database.db import Base


UsersRolesTable = Table(
    "users_roles",
    Base.metadata,
    Column("user_id", ForeignKey("users.id"), primary_key=True),
    Column("role_id", ForeignKey("roles.id"), primary_key=True),
)
```

I created the CRUD util to read all the roles:

```
## roles\crud.py

from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

from . import models, schemas


def get_roles(db: Session):
    return db.query(models.Role).all()
```

And the the router:

```
## roles\v1\router.py

from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends, HTTPException
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

from .. import schemas, crud
from src.database.db import SessionLocal, engine

router = APIRouter()

# Dependency
def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

@router.get("/", response_model=list[schemas.Role])
def read_roles(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    roles = crud.get_roles(db)
    return roles
```

When trying the request, I get a 500 error and the log of my FastAPI terminal reads:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper Mapper[Role(roles)], 
expression 'User' failed to locate a name ('User'). If this is a class name, 
consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'src.usersDomain.roles.models.Role'> 
class after both dependent classes have been defined.
```

If I import the User and Role classes respectively into the roles and users models, I get a circular import error from python.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Posting the solution I found.
Just need to import ALL the models in the same db.py file where the DeclarativeBase is defined.

Updated db.py file

```
## db.py

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, DeclarativeBase
from src.config import settings

engine = create_engine(settings.db_connection_string, echo=True)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

from src.usersDomain.users.models import User
from src.usersDomain.roles.models import Role
from src.usersDomain.permissions.models import Permission
from src.usersDomain.accounts.models import Account
from src.usersDomain.idps.models import Idp
```

Don't really grasped my way into python yet, but this is now working :)